# How to pass a integer and character type at runtime

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

I'm using subprocess in Python and passing ec2 instance id at runtime..while giving instance id it is taking as a string and throwing error saying instance id is not valid. Please don't suggest boto3 package as my company restricted of using it.My question is how can I send the character+integer+special character at runtime.

Pgm:

```
#!/bin/python
import subprocess
import sys
def describe_one(instanceid):
    subprocess.call(["aws", "ec2", "describe-instances", "--instance-ids", '"instanceid"'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    instanceid=sys.argv[1]
    describe_one(instanceid)
```

Output

```
# ./sample.py i-061e41edcc2afc01
```

> An error occurred (InvalidInstanceID.Malformed) when calling the DescribeInstances operation: Invalid id: ""instanceid""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you intending to pass the literal string `"instanceid"`?
Surely you mean to use its value?

```
subprocess.call(["aws", "ec2", "describe-instances", "--instance-ids", f'"{instanceid}"'])
```

or

```
subprocess.call(["aws", "ec2", "describe-instances", "--instance-ids", '"{}"'.format(instanceid)])
```

if not using Python3.6+

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with "passing integer or character types", whatever that means.

You are passing the literal value `"instanceid"`, complete with quotes, rather than the value of the instanceid argument to your script. You did do both sets of quotes.

(And really, you should take up this silly "restriction" about using boto3 with your boss. You can't be expected to do your gin without the correct tools.)